# Slow nginx page load

Tags: php, nginx

need some help to analyse my nginx installation. I've a very slow page start. Analysing using GTMETRIX show that something is blocking my page load. The page will slow load at first but then burst after several second the url is inijie.com (sorry for my english)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BVTp.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is TTFB (Time to first byte) which tells you exactly when the server begins outputting the requested page.

I get 3.9s TTFB from good-quality fiber in Denmark on it.

A high TTFB can have multiple reasons, generally slow page generation by the web server-application which could be tweaked out depending on the workload it's presented. [Ilya Grigorik](https://www.igvita.com/2013/12/16/optimizing-nginx-tls-time-to-first-byte/) has a post on the subject where he shaves off 300ms from 1.8s.

Comment: Is there anything i can do to lower my TTFB, it's been frustating for me to lower my server TTFB. i host at digitalocean, what's the overal TTFB for their singapore data center ?